# Unzip Data set in Google Drive/colab-Python

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have some data in an 8GB .tar file format. I added the data to my drive, but unfortunately the file is added as a shortcut.

I can't unzip the file using Python in Google Colab. Does anyone have ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the package tarfile for the extraction. before that you have to check the file you copy from your computer if it's a shortcut or the real file. (PS : another check is for your remeaning storage capacity in the GDrive if it fits your archive)

```
import tarfile


fname = "<YOUR FILE NAME>"
tar = tarfile.open(fname, "r:")
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
```

it will decompress your file in the same location as the archive in your drive.